# Two ways of creating a flask-SQLAlchemy BaseQuery object - only one works, why?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This question is a simplification of "[Filter relationships and paginate in Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727155/filter-relationships-and-paginate-in-flask-sqlalchemy)", and an answer here would probably yield a solution there too.

Say I have a simple model class Design:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Design(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'design'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    designname = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

I can get a Flask-SQLAlchemy BaseQuery object like this:

```
>>> Design.query
<flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x7f0b29c63990>
```

And I can get data back as you would expect:

```
>>> Design.query.all()
[<item1>, <item2>, <item3>]
```

I can also get a BaseQuery object this way (which I think is necessary for more complex query, e.g., one with joins):

```
>>> db.Query(Design)
<flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery object at 0x7f0b29c6fdd0>
```

It looks like it should be the same object type - indeed, the SQL generated is identical:

```
>>> str(db.Query(Design)) ==  str(Design.query)
True
```

And yet, when I try the all() method here, it doesn't work:

```
>>> db.Query(Design).all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<debugger>", line 1, in <module>
db.Query(Design).all()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2320, in all
return list(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2437, in __iter__
self.session._autoflush()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_autoflush'
```

EDIT: I believe the problem is that the second approach is not attaching a session to the BaseQuery object.  The first method has one:

```
>>> Design.query.session
<flask_sqlalchemy.SignallingSession object at 0x7f0b29fbd510>
```

But the other approach does not:

```
>>> db.Query(Design).session is None
True
```

Any insight is much appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
db.session.query(Design).all()
```

`session.query` is how you would perform queries when using SQLAlchemy without Flask-SQLAlchemy.

*UPDATE*

To perform a join using Flask-SQLAlchemy's `BaseQuery`:

```
Design.query.join(YourOtherModel).all()
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I already know how to do this with a regular SQLAlchemy session.  I am specifically trying to create a *flask*_SQLAlchemy BaseQuery using this alternative syntax.  My reason for doing this is the same as the other SE question that I referenced - I want to use the Pagination provided in the BaseQuery class. I should have made that more clear on the question.

Comment: I guess I'm just unclear as to why you can't use `Design.query`.

Comment: If you can show me how to use the `Design.query` with a table join, that would be great and I'll accept the answer.  The reason I was trying to get at via the session object is that I need to do a table join -- in pure SQLAlchemy, it would look like `db.session.query(Parent, Child).join(Child).all()` -- so I had hoped that I could do that with the flask extensions, something like `db.Query(Parent, Child.join(Child).all()`, but that doesn't work.  My question is a simplification of this problem... what is flask's `db.Query` for anyway, if it doesn't return a session-bound object?

Comment: `Design.query.join(YourOtherModel).all()`

Comment: Yes, perfect.  Thank you for the help with my admittedly beginner question.

Comment: FWIW, it looks like I fell into #7 of the [10 common stumbling blocks for SQLAlchemy newbies](http://alextechrants.blogspot.com/2013/11/10-common-stumbling-blocks-for.html)