# python instantiate child instance from parent object

Tags: python, inheritance

I have an object which is instantiated from parent class(it will b variable at below example code)
and i want to use this object like a child class instance without knowledge about the member variable of parent class

is there any recommendation?

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass # some member variables are assigned
    pass

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        print("test")
    pass

b = A()
b.test() # error
```

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: @bdbd thank you for your reply. actually i use pyvisa library. i want to inherit Resource class and make own class. resource manager connect to the instrument and return Resource instance. so i just want to use returned Resource object like my own class

Comment: ```session = visa.ResourceManager.open_resource(visa_resource_name)``` in this situation. i want to use session like my own class object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by setting `__class__` of `b` to `B`. But read this first:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280789/6759844

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        pass # some member variables are assigned
    pass

class B(A):
    def test(self):
        print("test")
    pass

b = A()
b.__class__ = B
b.test() # error
```