# How to add @property to the base Group model in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, model

I want to be able to add a property to the group model

This is what I have been trying

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class GroupExtensions(Group):
    class Meta:
       proxy = True

    @property
    def assigned_property(self):
        return 'something'
```

I want to get this property from the base group model but somehow this doesn't work

```
group_instance.assigned_property
```

Where group_instance is an instance of the Group model

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/models/#querysets-still-return-the-model-that-was-requested). So the only way for you to be able to use `assigned_property` is to query the groups through `GroupExtensions`. But there is a way to make this work, although you should be [careful about doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280789/6759844):

```
group_instance.__class__ = GroupExtensions
print(group_instance.assigned_property)
```

Comment: Oh I believe then the only way to achieve it is by tweaking the rules
Thanks for the help 
Really appreciated :)